# How do I use a Laravel value within PHP tags

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel value which I am able to retrieve using

```
{{$patient->dob}}
```

I would like to use this value in the same php file but withing php

```
 @php
   $birthDate = {{$patient->dob}};
@endphp
```

This is giving me an error.

I have also done this

```
 @php
   $birthDate = echo "{{$patient->dob}}";
@endphp
```

If I remove the Braces, like shown below I am getting 'Undefined offset:' error

```
 $birthDate = $patient->dob;
```

What is the right way of doing it.

Comment: no need to use braces "{ }"

Comment: If I remove braces, I am getting 'Undefined offset Error'

Comment: You should avoid putting logic in a blade-file! Logic belongs in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the variable.

```
@php
   echo $birthDate = $patient->dob ?? 'No DOB' ;
@endphp
```

I know it's not right way to work this way in laravel, but I guess you have some other code within php tag.

Comment: @MartinMbae: try `echo $birthDate = $patient->dob ?? 'No DOB' ;`

Answer (score 1):

**This is perfect way to retrive data from controller**

```
{{$patient->dob}}
```

*check if value in `$patient->dob` so retrieve value otherwise give null*

```
{{ $patient->dob ?? '' }}  // or {{ $patient->dob ?? '-' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
{{ $patient->dob ?? '' }}
```

sometime i try this too.

```
@isset($patient)
{{ $patient->dob ?? '' }}
@endisset
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check in "$patient" object "dob" key exists or not.

```
@php
    $birthDate = "";
    if($patient->dob != undefined)
    {
      $birthDate = $patient->dob;
    }
  @endphp

 <p>{{ $birthDate }}</p>
```